# exceptions not working cross compiling with clang and cmake for arm cortex m4, and "got" section is generated

Tags: c++, exception, clang, cortex-m, linker-scripts

I have been trying lately to compile firmware with Clang and CMake, using Toolchain files, for C++. I can get it normally working without exceptions. A problem arises when I use exceptions.

LLVM version: 13.0.0
CMake version: 3.21.3
CPU: STM32L432KC, ARM Cortex M4

To successfully compile the firmware I use precompiled `libc`, `libm`, `libgcc` and `libstdc++` bundled with ARM GNU GCC Toolchain, version 10.3.2021-10.

I won't put the entire toolchain file here. Trust me that the paths to the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, `CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_LINKER` are good.

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT`, which define initial compile flags for C language, are defined like so:

```
-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
-nodefaultlibs
--sysroot=${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/arm-none-eabi
-flto
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
# For <iostream>, <string>, ...
-isystem "${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_VERSION}/" 
# For <bits/*>, ...
-isystem "${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_VERSION}/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/"
-fexceptions
```

`ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH` is the root path to the mentioned ARM GNU GCC Toolchain. `ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_VERSION` is equal to `10.3.1`.

The linker flags, defined with `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT`:

```
-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
-nodefaultlibs
--sysroot=${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/arm-none-eabi
-flto
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections
-Wl,--gc-sections
-flto
-fexceptions
# Path to standard libraries: libc, libm, ...
-L"${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/"
# Path to libgcc
-L"${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/${ARM_GNU_TOOLCHAIN_GCC_VERSION}/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard/"
-lc -lm -lnosys -lstdc++ -lgcc")
```

If in the binary there is no, `try ... catch` block. Everything compiles just fine, but if there is at least one block:

```
try
{
    throw std::runtime_error{"Some error!"};
} catch (const std::exception&e)
{
    printf("Error: %s\r\n", e.what());
}
```

The linker inputs the `.got` section, before `.data` section without being instructed within the linker script. The RAM start address is 0x20000000. `objdump` output:

```
...
Contents of section .got:
 20000000 848f0108                             ....
Contents of section .data:
 20000004 00000000 00000000 08000020 08000020  ........... ... 
 20000014 10000020 10000020 18000020 18000020  ... ... ... ... 
 20000024 20000020 20000020 28000020 28000020   ..  .. (.. (.. 
 20000034 30000020 30000020 38000020 38000020  0.. 0.. 8.. 8.. 
...
```

My linker script, generated by CubeMX, has LMA `.data` section, which shall be the first in RAM.:

```
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(8);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
```

As you can see in the comment, `_sdata` will be used by the startup code to initialize `data` in RAM. The problem is that `_sdata` will be set to 0x20000000, not 0x20000008, where the first global variable lies. This means that all the global variables will have wrong values.

As a workaround, I have added a `.got` section which uses all the `got*` input sections:

```
...
  .fini_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >FLASH

  .got :
  {
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.got)
    *(.got*)
    . = ALIGN(8);
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
...
```

Since `.got` section is related to dynamic symbol resolution, I am not really fluent with it. I use only static libraries to compile the firmware, since I write bare-metal programs targeted one binary per project.

The main issue is that the exceptions don't work correctly. No exceptions are caught within the above `try ... catch ...` block. The firmware ends within `Default_Handler`.

I guess it's related to the `.got` section generated by clang. Clang is not able to properly link the compiler builtins from `libgcc` to handle the exceptions.

Could you help me in debugging and fixing that?

Comment: Not necessary relevant to the problem, but perhaps `C_FLAGS` shouldn't be involved when compiling C++ code.

Comment: @user7860670 you mean to compile C++ only with `isystem` flags and `fexceptions`?

Comment: No, my point is that `C_FLAGS` are to be ignored when compiling C++ code so it makes no sense to alter them and you should have been using `CXX_FLAGS` instead.

Comment: Oh yeas, maybe I was not clear enough. I will remove mentioning C flags, since they are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Wl,--target2=rel` flag when compiling.

---

I have created a post on the llvm-dev mailing list, which can be found [here](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2021-November/153810.html). Peter Smith has helped to resolve the problem and pointed to the solution.